# Azure Network Security Groups not showing in Portal

Tags: azure, azure-security

I am getting a bit frustrated with the Azure "Preview" Portal.

I have just created a new NSG with the PowerShell:

```
# Create a new NSG
New-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Location "West Europe" -Name "NAME"
```

But it is not showing in the Portal:

[image]

But is listed when I do:

```
Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "NAME"
```

Is this a normal behavior? or did I something wrong?